# Difference between the average heights

Tags: statistics

Please help me to solve

In a study to test whether there is a difference between the average height of adult females born in two different countries, random samples yielded the following results:

$n_1 = 120,$ $\bar x_1 = 62.7,$ $s_1 = 2.50;\;$ 
  $n_2 = 150,$ $\bar x_2= 61.8,$ $s_2 = 2.62,$

where the measurements are in inches. Use 0.05 level of significance to test the difference between the average heights.

Comment: Hints: Variances of the means, variance of the difference in the means, standard error of the difference in the means, normal distribution test of the difference (since sample sizes are large)

Answer (score 0):

Heights in most populations are approximately normal and sample sizes are large, so it
is reasonable to treat the data as normal and use a two-sample t test.

There are two versions
of the two sample t test. One in which you assume population variances
of the two groups are equal, and the other in which you don't
make that assumption. Because sample sizes are unequal the two
formulas will give slightly different values of the T statistic.

*Strictly speaking,* you should use a t test because population variances are
unknown, but due to the large sample sizes, the critical value
for the T statistic is about 2.0. If you are using software you *must*
use a t test (rather than an approximating z test} because a z test
procedure will ask you for population variances, which you don't have.

I will show you output from Minitab statistical software for the
'Welch test' (which does not assume equal population variances), and
leave it to you to use the appropriate formula from your text
to compute the T statistic for yourself.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample    N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       120  68.70   2.50     0.23
2       150  61.80   2.62     0.21

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  6.900
95% CI for difference:  (6.284, 7.516)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
   T-Value = 22.06  P-Value = 0.000  DF = 259
```

Because $T = 22.06$ with absolute value (by far) exceeding the critical value $1.97 \approx 2.0$ (for DF = 259),
you can reject the null hypothesis that the population mean
heights are equal, at the 5% level.  Another indication that
population means differ at the 5% level of significance is that the 95% confidence interval
for the difference in means does not include $0$.

Software usually gives a P-value. You can reject at level $\alpha$
if the P-value is smaller than $\alpha.$ So here, you could reject
even at the 1% level or even the 0.1% level. [`P-value = 0.000` means
that the the P-value is less than 0.0005.]

Although a 'pooled t test' (assuming equal population variances) gives
a slightly different value of the test statistic ($T = 21.94$), the
P-value is still less than 0.0005, and the conclusion is the same.